# Capital in terms of labor

Tags: microeconomics, production-function, cobb-douglas, elasticity-of-substitution

I have a question that asks to find $\frac{\partial K}{\partial L} $
from $Q=cL^aK^b$, when $Q$ and $c$ are constants. It lists 4 answer choices but I’m just not sure how to approach it. Implicit function theorem? Chain rule... any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

--Update--
Well I thought about this some more and think I got it:
The total differential can be written as:
$$dQ=\frac{acK^b}{L^{1-a}}dL+\frac{bcL^a}{K^{1-b}}dK=0$$
dividing by $dL$ and c and moving terms, gives
$$\frac{aK^b}{L^{1-a}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial L}=-\frac{bL^a}{K^{1-b}}\frac{\partial K}{\partial L}$$
Dividing though by $L$ and $K$ and expressing it in terms $\frac{\partial K}{\partial L}$ gives:

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial L} = -\frac{aK}{bL}$,

which I hope is correct.

Comment: +1 for effort shown.  I obtained the same result by rearranging the equation as $K=Q^{1/b}c^{-1/b}L^{-a/b}$ and then differentiating.